# Textbox field returns word 'undefined' when typing a value

Tags: javascript

I’m trying to create an input form that inputs “-” after 3 character. Like this “123-456-789″.

Everything is all good, except when I type inside the input field, the word “undefined” shows up after 3 characters. I guess the problem is on my browser, its working on Internet Explorer 11 but when I run it on IE7 the word 'undefined' occurs on the input field. I want it to be compatible to IE7 also. Hope someone helps me.

This is what i have:

```
$('.taxidno').live('keypress', function () {
  var theEvent = window.event;
  var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
  key = String.fromCharCode(key);
  var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/;
  if (!regex.test(key)) {
    theEvent.returnValue = false;
    if (theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
  }
  var str = $(this).val().replace(/-/g, '');
  var newVal2 = '';
  var returnVal = '';
  if (str.length > 19) {
    return false;
  }
  if (str.length != 0 && str.length % 3 == 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      newVal2 += str[i];
      if (newVal2.length != 0 && newVal2.length % 3 == 0) {
        returnVal += newVal2 + '-';
        newVal2 = '';
      }
    }
    $(this).val(returnVal);
  }
});
```

Comment: There's a nice plugin for that http://plugins.jquery.com/mask/

Comment: Open up the console and see if there are errors

Comment: I tried it but i dont see any error.